# Kivy: Why is my TextInput cursor/caret defaulting to red?

Tags: python, kivy

Note the caret color in the my TextInput is defaulting to red. I'm unsure why this would be happening or how to change it?

[image]

This is my code:

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return TextInput(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what caused this to default to red but I changed it with:

`TextInput(text='Hello world', cursor_color=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1))`